# set the value of index.max_result_window

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

as the title says, how do I set this from within my spring data elasticsearch applciaiton (spring boot)?

I can see in the exception traces that it is set to 10000.  I need slightly more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to increase the max_result_window, you should set this property when creating your index.
Using spring boot, you can have something like this (Example for max_result_window = 15000:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainClass implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    public ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainClass.class).close()
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        elasticsearchTemplate.createIndex(Entity.class, "max_result_window = 15000");
}
```

Comment: this will throw index already exists exception, because createIndex(Entity.class, "max_result_window = 15000") doesn't check if index exists. Better to use createIndex(Entity.class) (actually we don't need to call it explicitly, it will be called when server starts if @Document(createIndex=true)), from source code I see it will check if index exists, and add annotation  @Setting(settingPath="/path/setting.json") on Entity.class, and set {"max_result_window" : 15000} in setting.json.

Answer (score 1):

Simply an entry in your application.properties:

```
spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.index.max_result_window=15000
```

Comment: This is deprecated now. Just do a PUT /_settings with 
`{
  "index.max_result_window": 20000
}`